# Can I declare method to return Class object with restriction to subclasses of given type in Java?

Tags: java, class, reflection, types, return-value

Suppose I declare some abstract method, that will return Class object (like Dog.class, Cat.class), like this:

```
abstract public Class getProducedAnimalType();
```

Can I force clients extending this API to return only Class objects that represents classes, wchich are subclassess of Animal.class ? something like:

```
abstract public Class<representing subclass of Animal> getProducedAnimalType();
```

So the client extending my class cannot write:

```
public Class getProducedAnimalType() {
   // Integer not extends Animal!, shoud not compile!
   return Integer.class; 
}
```

but can:

```
public Class getProducedAnimalType() {
   return Fish.class; // Fish extends Animal
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the return type `Class` to `Class<? extends Animal>`. The following code will allow to return `Cat.class` and `Dog.class`, but won't allow to return `Integer.class` :

```
abstract public Class<? extends Animal> getProducedAnimalType();
```

The client can write the following code and will compile fine:

```
public Class<? extends Animal> getProducedAnimalType() 
{
   return Fish.class; // Fish extends Animal
}
```

But the following code won't compile:

```
public Class getProducedAnimalType() 
{
   return Integer.class; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Class<? extends Animal> getProducedType() {
// return Integer.class; // compile time error: incompatible types
    return Dog.class;
}
```